# Displaying ArcMap 10.2 labels in KML

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, kml, google-earth

Goal: To export a labeled geo-referenced point layer created in ArcMap 10.2 to KML and have Google Earth only display labels of certain points when zoomed out past a certain scale (to avoid clutter).

I am tasked with creating a graduated circle map to be displayed in Google Earth. Here are the steps I took:

1. Exported table with values to ArcMap
2. Created graduated circles shapefile based on values in a column. Bigger values take on bigger circles
3. Labeled the circles based on another column of the attribute table. Labled with Mapplex label engine
4. Exported entire map to KML using map to KML conversion tool in ArcMap
5. Opened the KML file in Google Earth. Having all labels display at once clutters the map with labels

Questions:

1. How do I make it so that the labels for big circles appear when zoomed out and labels for smaller circles appear when zoomed in closer than a certain scale?

I tried doing this in ArcMap by setting the labels for smaller circles to not display when zoomed past a certain scale, but this doesn't affect the resulting KML file.

2. How do I make labels appear only when I hover my mouse over the point of interest in Google Earth? This is another option for me to reduce label clutter.

I am not that familiar with KML and don't know where to start.

Comment: As a relatively new user please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question here.